# Hide past date from JSON via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file with information in it, there's title, date, etc, etc,

Format in the JSON:

```
date:"01/01/2001"
```

My current code to arrange by date

```
$(element).find('.ct-googleMap--search').val('');
arrayMarker = [];
dataMarkers = data;
dataMarkers.sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime();
});
```

Now I want to add hiding dates that have passed. I've tried some options, but now I'm here.

Comment: Have you considered creating a new JSON of only valid dates instead of hiding expired dates?

Comment: what is dataMarkers content? can you show it up?

Comment: Do you mean you want to physically remove the property from the object? If so [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) Allows you to manipulate each element in an array. Or do you mean hiding in terms of values shown in the DOM because thats a completely different question.

Comment: hiding it when the data with a date that is older then current, so i wont have to update the json every day, but it auto filters .

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function?

```
var now = new Date();
//filter out old values first, so the sort is working with a smaller result
dataMarkers = data.filter(function(d) { 
  return d > now;
});
dataMarkers.sort(function (a, b) {
    //equal values don't require the date object construction
    if (a.date === b.date) {
        return 0;
    }
    return new Date(a.date) > new Date(b.date); //based on borisdiakur's comment
});
```